# Why the react component is not returning the current data from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have a react app that is connected with redux. The component has a form that makes a PUT call to the api when the form is submitted. When I submit the form, I can see that redux gets updated accordingly but when I try to access the redux state as a prop in my component, the props data does not return the current data and is off by 1. For example, here's the data in my redux store:

**Redux store:**

[image: redux store]

When I do `console.log("THIS PROPS: ", this.props)` in my component, I see that it `accountError` is showing up as `null`

[image]

When I dispatch the action again the second time, only then I see that I am getting the data from redux in my props:

[image]

Here is the code that I have currently:

**OrgAccount.js**

```
import { registerOrgAccount, getListOfOrgsAndAccts } from "../../store/actions";

handleSubmit = () => {
  this.props.registerOrgAccount(this.state)
  console.log("THIS PROPS: ", this.props)
  if(this.props.accountError === null) {
    this.toggleTab(this.state.activeTab + 1);
  }
};

<Link
  to="#"
  className="btn w-lg"
  onClick={() => {
    if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
      this.handleSubmit();
    }
  }}
>
  Next
</Link>

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  const { accounts, accountError, loading } = state.OrgAccount;
  return { accounts, accountError, loading };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      getListOfOrgsAndAccts: () => {
        dispatch(getListOfOrgsAndAccts())
    },
     registerOrgAccount: (data) => {
        dispatch(registerOrgAccount(data))
     },
     
  }
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrgAccount);
```

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
    accountError: null, accountsError: null, message: null, loading: null
}

const orgAccount = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT:
            state = {
                ...state,
                account: null,
                loading: true,
                // accountError: null
            }
            break;
       
        case REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT_SUCCESSFUL:
            state = {
                ...state,
                account: action.payload,
                loading: false,
                accountError: null
            }
            break;
        case REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT_FAILED:
            state = {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                accountError: action.payload ? action.payload.response : null
            }
            break;
        ...
        default:
            state = { ...state };
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default orgAccount;
```

**Action**

```
export const registerOrgAccount = (account) => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT,
        payload: { account }
    }
}

export const registerOrgAccountSuccessful = (account) => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT_SUCCESSFUL,
        payload: account
    }
}

export const registerOrgAccountFailed = (error) => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER_ORG_ACCOUNT_FAILED,
        payload: error
    }
}
```

**Saga.js**

```
import { registerOrgAccountSuccessful, registerOrgAccountFailed, getListOfOrgsAndAcctsSuccessful, getListOfOrgsAndAcctsFailed } from './actions';
import { putOrgAccount } from '../../../helpers/auth_helper';

function* registerOrgAccount({ payload: { account } }) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(putOrgAccount, {
            orgId: account.orgId,
            accountNumber: account.accountNumber,
            accountName: account.accountName,
            accountCode: account.accountCode,
            urlLink: account.urlLink,
            location: account.location,
            accountType: account.accountType,
            address: account.address,
            city: account.city,
            state: account.state,
            zip: account.zip,
            country: account.country,
            email: account.email,
            eula: "blah"
        });
        yield put(registerOrgAccountSuccessful(response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(registerOrgAccountFailed(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown where `registerOrgAccountFailed` gets called.

Comment: Hi Bafsky, thanks for the response. I have updated my post by including Saga.js which shows where `registerOrgAccountFailed` gets called

Comment: Just an observation: never do `state = { ...state };`  in the `default` case - that has the potential to trigger a lot of unnecessary rerenders, as that state now always become a new object even if it did not change. Just omit it.

Comment: @phry - thanks for the note...will take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the root cause here, I think it helps to know a little about immutability and how React rerenders. In short, React will rerender when it detects reference changes. This is why mutating a prop, wont trigger a rerender.

With that in mind, at the time you call handleSubmit, *this.props.accountError* is simply a reference to a value somewhere in memory. When you dispatch your action and your state is updated, a new reference will be created, which will trigger a rerender of your component. However the handleSubmit function that was passed to your element still references the old this.props.accountError, which is why it is still null.

You could get around this by implementing your check in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. E.g. something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.accountError === null && this.props.accountError !== null) {
    this.toggleTab(this.state.activeTab + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for the explanation. Do you know what needs to be done to fix this issue?

Comment: You could use the [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method. Check if accountError is not null, and then update your state accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. That worked out really well. Really appreciate it.